# can't parse JSON from javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm newbie in javascript and My project can't use AJAX or any Framework . . .

It's simple code but still curious what's wrong with it

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="onejs.js"></script>
    <link href="onecss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="myDiv" class="subMenu" onclick="test(this)">CLICK</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

onejs.js

```
function test(id) { 
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.id = 'dynScript';
    s.type='text/javascript';
    s.src = "http://echo.jsontest.com/one/111oneoneone/key/value";
    var obj = JSON.parse(s);
    id.innerHTML = (obj.key);
}
```

When I click in "CLICK" it doesn't change.

Comment: *"My project can't use AJAX or any Framework"*. You should probably start by looking for what is AJAX.

Comment: Long story short: you can't do it like this. Either you get the JSON with AJAX and you parse it with `JSON.parse`, or the remote host providing the JSON allows you to specify a consumer callback (google JSONP).

Comment: Actually It can use AJAX but data from real url has a lot info. So I have to manage it before display it and I don't want to show JSON's url in front site. Sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to load JSON as if it was a JavaScript script. It isn't, so you can't.

Normally you would use the XMLHttpRequest object for this type of job.

However, since you are ruled out Ajax (the process of using JavaScript to make HTTP requests), this isn't an option, so you would have to embed the data into the HTML when it initially loads.

Comment: But then, this would be "AJAX".

Comment: OK My api can send data via XML too. So I should go on XML ,right ?

Comment: XML isn't JavaScript either, so changing data format to that wouldn't help.

Comment: You can use XMLHttpRequest to fetch any kind of data. It only has XML in the name because the developers needed to persuade management to put it into the next release of the product and XML was a cool buzzword at the time.